# Jira get issue reset api getting failed throwing error of Forbidden 403 cloudflare

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, jira, jira-rest-api

I have facing some Cloudflare 403 Unauthroized error, Getting Forbidden, You don't have permission to view this. Please contact your system administrator.

```
let Jira_URL = "https://jira.mydomain.com/";
let Jira_Email_Address = "mail of jira account";
let Jira_API_Token = "my personal access token";

let url = Jira_URL + "rest/api/3/issue/TICKETID";
let credentials = Utilities.base64Encode(Jira_Email_Address + ":" + Jira_API_Token);
let header = { 
    "Authorization": "Basic " + credentials,
    "Accept": "application/json"
} 
let options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": header,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
} 
console.log(options)
let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
console.log(res);
```

Below response im getting

> {"message":"Forbidden. You don't have permission to view this. Please
> contact your system
> administrator.","status_code":403,"aud":"dsfer23r3wersdfsffsf232423rsf3432","ray_id":"dsfwer34234sfad","ip_address":"12.345.67.8","is_warp":false,"is_gateway":false,"mtls_status":"NONE"}

Comment: I have tried with postman aswell but getting same error only. And in that project my role is administrator, leader, and developer.

Comment: I think you are missing the Content-Type header. See if this helps: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/

Comment: @pringi tried with that also bro.